Linux Mint - should I install fonts in "~/.fonts" or "~/.local/share/fonts"?
This is for a user-level installation, not system-wide. My understanding is system-wide fonts go in /usr/share/fonts but I like to avoid making system wide changes whenever possible even though I'm the only one who uses this computer.
I have been looking, and I am finding conflicting information, some (mostly older) sources say to use ~/.fonts, others tell me to use ~/.local/share/fonts, one article mentions ~/.local/share/fonts/truetype, presumably for TrueType fonts specifically.
I'd like to just place or symlink my font files in one folder and have applications pick up whatever font formats they support.
TL;DR:
Is there a "best" or "ideal" location to put font files in [insert current year]?
Also, can I symlink one folder to the other for ease of use? Should I symlink, say ~/.fonts to ~/.local/share/fonts? Does it even matter?

You should use ~/.local/share/fonts, because according to the Arch Wiki, .fonts is deprecated.

Arch isn't Mint; maybe ~/.fonts isn't deprecated in Mint/Ubuntu/Debian.
